# slow boot up and weird interface when entering password for laptop

Tags: package-management

```
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-xenial.list:3
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-xenial.list:4
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-xenial.list:3
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-xenial.list:4
```

...got this after doing grub upgrade

Comment: The initial `W` indicates a `Warning`, you could ignore it. Or you could solve the problem by removing (or #commenting) the duplicate lines from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-xenial.list`